# my data is not posting to django rest api using ajax

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, rest

somehow my data is not posting to /api/recipe/recipes/ my html

```
    {% extends 'base.html' %}
    {% block content %}
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    
    <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <title>Create a Recipe</title>
    </head>
    
    <body class="">
      <form>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <br>
        <label for="T">Title: </label>
        <input type="text" name="T" value="">
        <br>
        <label for="Ingr">Ingredients: </label>
        <select class="" name="Ingr">
          {% for ing in Ing %}
          <option value="ing.pk">{{ing}}</option>
          {%endfor%}
        </select>
        <br>
        <label for="Tag">Tags: </label>
        <select class="" name="Tag">
          {% for tag in Tag %}
          <option value="Tag.pk">{{tag}}</option>
          {%endfor%}
        </select>
        <br>
        <label for="Time">Time: </label>
        <input type="text" name="Time" value="">
        <br>
        <label for="P">Price: </label>
        <input type="text" name="P" value="">
        <br>
        <label for="link">Link: </label>
        <input type="text" name="link" value="">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Post">
      </form>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
      <script>
       $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
      var data = {
        title: $('[name="T"]').val(),
        tags: $('[name="Tag"]').val(),
        ingredients: $('[name="Ingr"]').val(),
        time_minutes: $('[name="Time"]').val(),
        price: $('[name="P"]').val(),
        link: $('[name="link"]').val()
      };

      var headers = {
        'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}'
      }; // Inject our token into the javascript using a template tag
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        headers: headers, // Set the headers in the request
        url: '/api/recipe/recipes/',
        success: function(res) {
          console.log(res)
        },
      });
  })
      </script>
    </body>
    
    </html>
    {%endblock%}
```

I am trying to post this form to the rest framework in the URL above the data isn't even posting in the console if you have any solution please help me thank you in advance

I am getting these errors in the console when I submit

```
Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> ((index):101)
    at HTMLFormElement.dispatch (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3)
    at HTMLFormElement.q.handle (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3)
```

those 3 errors are a nightmare for me i treid allot of ways and none of them worked i really would appreciate any help :D

Comment: One issue is you need a closing `</script>` tag after this `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js">`

Comment: it didnt fix my error i saw peaople use something like this $(document).on("click",’.shares’, function (event) { does this work? and if it does can u do it on my code? Thank you,

Comment: What if you remove `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>` entirely? I wonder if importing jquery twice is causing issues.

Comment: unfortunately, it didn't work

Comment: I'm stumped then. If I import the scripts and `console.log(typeof $.ajax)`, it says "function"

Comment: i am getting undefined

Comment: do you want my full code?

Comment: Sure. Also, can you try deleting the this import `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: i am commiting 1 sec

Answer (score 0):

I expect it is  something to do with how you are referencing the library, emulating your code here works (well, it makes the request anyway). Import multiple versions of the same library is likely to cause trouble, but I'm not sure that it would give the error you have been getting though. In this example, from your code, I've stripped out the iterating through django context variables, but these shouldn't have anything to do with the probelm you have been experiencing.

```js
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  var data = {
    title: $('[name="T"]').val(),
    time_minutes: $('[name="Time"]').val(),
    price: $('[name="P"]').val(),
    link: $('[name="link"]').val()
  };

  var headers = {
    'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}'
  }; // Inject our token into the javascript using a template tag
  
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    headers: headers, // Set the headers in the request
    url: '/api/recipe/recipes/',
    success: function(res) {
      console.log(res);
    },
    error: function(res) {
      var errorMessage = res.status + ': ' + res.statusText;
      console.error('Error Posting: ', errorMessage);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <br>
  
  <label for="T">Title: </label>
  <input type="text" name="T" value="">
  <br>
  
  <label for="Time">Time: </label>
  <input type="text" name="Time" value="">
  <br>

  <label for="P">Price: </label>
  <input type="text" name="P" value="">
  <br>
  
  <label for="link">Link: </label>
  <input type="text" name="link" value="">
  <br>
  
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Post">
</form>
```

Comment: it didn't work here is my full code https://github.com/osamada/recipe-app-api.git

Comment: I managed to get it to work by updating the script tag to **jquery**:

`<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

I got this script tag direct from the jquery website at https://code.jquery.com/ and clicked the **minified** link

Comment: thank you so much the error is gone but my data is still not posting to the rest framework

Comment: I ended up moving most scripts to the `head` block. It used to be recommended to put scripts at the end of the `body`, but I feel that is largely outdated advice, I recommend looking at `async` and `defer` `script` attributes instead (although I used neither in my test as they didn't work). I also added `python manage.py collectstatic &&` just before the `runserver` command in the docker-compose.yml file, just to ensure all custom django templates are collected on every startup (I just do this as standard).

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it, I had another jquery script in my base.html that's why it wasn't working I deleted it and it works now thanks to everyone for helping me